# Writing data from the filename of a .wav file to excel, using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have multiple .wav files in a folder, named like "00_artist_name_-_title_name.wav" and I want to write this information -split up in "artist name" in one column and "title name" in another for example" all in one row for each .wav file. I use xlsxwriter.

Unfortunately I am kinda stuck and do not know how to get at this problem, so I only have this so far:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('excel_test.xlsx')

worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('metadata')


#Inserting the configured TABLE_HEAD using a created format
worksheet1.write_row('A1', TABLE_HEAD, header_format)

#My try at solving this problem, unfortunately not working.
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        worksheet1.write_row([filename])


workbook.close()
```

**EDIT:** 
So after a bit of trying I got my code to get the filename of a .wav, split the strings removing unwanted characters like "_" and "-" and paste the wanted information in excel.

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_test):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".wav"):
            (xxinterpret, xxtitle)=file.split("_-_", 1)
            (tracknr, xinterpret)=xxinterpret.split("_", 1)
            #removing "-" + "_" + ".wav"
            interpret=xinterpret.replace("_", " ")
            xtitle=xxtitle.replace("_", " ")
            (title, extension)=xtitle.split(".")
            #write information in row
            worksheet1.write(1, 1, interpret)
            worksheet1.write(1, 2, title)
            worksheet1.write(1, 3, tracknr)
```

This might be quite confusing, especially the variables xxtitle, xtitle and then only title. Since I am quite new to Python, and programming in general, any advices on how to solve this in a smooth way are very, very welcome and appreciated.